# How can I use URL in my html page in django?

Tags: django, url

hi when I want to use URL in my action tag I get an error URL not found
what should I do please help me!

```
app_name = 'accounts'
urlpatterns = [
path('signup',views.signup_view, name='signup'),
path('login',views.login_view, name = 'login'),
]


urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('about/',views.about),
path('',views.home),
path('articles/', include('articles.urls')),
path('accounts/',include('accounts.urls')),

]


<form class="site-form" action="{% urls'accounts:signup'%}" 
method="post">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tag is named [**`{% url … %}`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url), not <s>`{% urls … %}`</s>, furthermore there should be a space between the name of the tag (here `url`) and the parameter. So you should impelement this with:

```
<form action="{% url 'accounts:signup' %}" class="site-form" method="post">
```